# NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory with Ruby spreadsheet gem

Tags: ruby, excel

I'm using the Ruby gem spreadsheet in Ruby v1.9.3 like this:

```
require "spreadsheet"

book = Spreadsheet.open("Test.xls")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMemoryError: failed to allocate memory
```

The version of the spreadsheet gem is 0.9.5.  The spreadsheet is an Excel 97-2003 Workbook.

This is a surprising error to me because the spreadsheet is not large.  It's only about 0.5 MB.

Any suggestions?  How could I do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution, try doing this

```
require "spreadsheet"
book = Spreadsheet.open("Test.xls").worksheet 0
```

I had the same problem, opening a spreadsheet at whole could be difficult so just take one worksheet at a time using index or name.This is what worked for me.